# Hide language flag on this language page?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have 2 languages on my Drupal 8 site and use Language Icons module for them:

- Latin and
- Celtic

I think it is not convenient to have both flags on each version. But D8 does not add language code class in body and I cannot hide flag.

Please where is solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want add class language to body. You can use **hook_preprocess_html** with code:

```
function Your_Theme_preprocess_html(&$vars){
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $vars['attributes']['class'][] = $language;
}
```

class current language will add to body.

Comment: your code is ok. but looking html-code once more I see language link has class is-active so i will use it. thanks for your job!

Comment: i use it to rebuild template for languages with right-to-left reading to regroup blocks. thank you!